# Wordcloud returns one word

Tags: r, word-cloud

R wordcloud returns only a single word."Soft"
Here is the code used to create the wordcloud

```
wordcloud(cambrdf$word,cambrdf$freq,random.order = F,col=terrain.colors(length(cambrdf$word),alpha = 0.5))
structure(list(word = c("goodby", "sky", "western", "are", "bride", 
"glitter", "golden", "heart", "keep", "reflect", "riversid", 
"set", "shimmer", "sun", "their", "undul", "willow", "young", 
"cambridg", "flow", "gentl", "leisur", "mud", "root", "sway", 
"tape", "waterwe", "will", "clear", "crumpl", "duckwe", "elm", 
"hold", "midst", "pool", "rainbow", "rainbowlik", "settl", "shade", 
"spring", "that", "tree", "where", "and", "greener", "laden", 
"long", "pole", "radianc", "seek", "starlight", "upstream", "with", 
"cambridgeridg", "cricket", "farewel", "for", "music", "peac", 
"yet", "away", "gentli", "singl", "sleev", "take", "came", "cloud", 
"just", "leav", "wave", "river", "the", "grass", "green", "water", 
"dream", "loud", "punt", "sing", "even", "now", "silent", "quiet", 
"soft"), freq = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -84L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check the default settings of `wordcloud`. By default the min.freq is 4. When applied to your dataset, will only return soft as this has a count of 3 or higher. If you set the min.freq lower to 2 you will get the last 19 words in your data.frame.

The code below will you the last 19 words.

```
wordcloud(cambrdf$word, cambrdf$freq, min.freq = 2, random.order = F, col = terrain.colors(length(cambrdf$word), alpha = 0.5))
```